# Use mktime on Date based on first day of month

Tags: php

Is there a way that I can have mktime go back a certain amount of months based of the first day of the month rather than the current day? Right now my code is echoing March instead of February because there is no 29 in February.

```
date("F Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') - 8, date('d'), date('Y')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the "day" parameter to 1:

```
date("F Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') - 8, 1, date('Y')))
```